# How can i convert thai date to english using PHP?

Tags: php, date

Currently i am doing format of date from `THAI` To `English` Language but it could not format date from `THAI` to `English`. I researched on **Google** but i could not found anything over there.

Following is my THAI date formate

```
15 กรกฎาคม 2562
```

Comment: First of all you need to realize that this is not about parsing a _Gregorian_ date to begin with, but that you are operating in a completely different calendar system here - the Buddhist calendar. (If you did not take that into account in your initial research, do so now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution with [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php
$search = [
    // Here thai months from 1 to 6
    'กรกฎาคม',
    // And the rest here
];
$replace = [
    // Here eng months from 1 to 6
    'July',
    // And the rest here
];

$tdate = '15 กรกฎาคม 2562';
$edate = str_replace($search, $replace, $tdate);

var_dump($edate);
```

Comment: Thank you So much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys.
I have solved this issues. Below is my code.

```
$date = explode(" " , "15 กรกฎาคม 2562");
$EnglishYear = $date[2] - 543;
$testKey = '';
$monthNamesThai = array("มกราคม","กุมภาพันธ์","มีนาคม","เมษายน","พฤษภาคม","มิถุนายน",
"กรกฎาคม","สิงหาคม","กันยายน","ตุลาคม","พฤษจิกายน","ธันวาคม");
$monthNameEnglish = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
foreach($monthNamesThai as $key => $monthNamesThai){
    if($date[1] == $monthNamesThai){
        $testKey = $key;
    }
}
$resultDate = $date[0]." ".$monthNameEnglish[$testKey]." ".$EnglishYear;
echo $resultDate;
```

Comment: Hi Parth, you should use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) which shorten the code and so it enhances readability of the code.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I have to make dynamically that's the reason I have used foreach loop.